# What exactly is happening when you install an app from the App Store when you already have the same app installed from the vendor?

Tags: mac-appstore

I installed 1Password from the package provided at the vendor's website. I noticed today that the App Store has 1Password as well, and I went ahead and installed it from there too to see what happened. The app installed like normal and as far as I can see, nothing changed. I was given no prompt, not asked permission to erase anything, etc. It just installed like any other app from the App Store.

What exactly happened? Did the App Store version automatically overwrite the one I manually installed? Did it just take ownership of the existing application? Or what?

Comment: If there aren't two 1Password apps in your `Applications` folder, then yes, it is likely that App Store did overwrite and *"took ownership on the installation / updates"* of the existing app (similar to how you upgrade an app - the app still uses your old existing data but replaces the old app with the updated version). (Tip: Better to avoid the app store though - remember that it never allows you to downgrade to a previous version of an app - so if you don't like the changes made to an updated app, you are stuck with it).